# Excel: Mapping months in the year with numerical value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

And I have a selection which looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is when a user selects what "Current Month" it is, the "Month Number" should map agaisnt what current month is selected and output the result. So for example if November is selected then the Month Number would be 11.

How do I do this? I want the formula to be in cell E4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter following formula in `Cell E4`

```
=INDEX(A31:A42,MATCH(E3,B31:B42,0))
```

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: @Json - Oops! Use `E3` instead of `E31`. My mistake.

Comment: Given that the number sequence matches the natural numerical month ordinals, `=month(datevalue("1/"&e3))` would also work.

Comment: @Jeeped - Thank you for this solution, look better.